# Logout approach for angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have started learning angularjs for two days, there a lot of new concepts that are new to me, i'm building a test project to my final project testing all the new different things so far,
I'm stuck in the logout, i have implement the ng-if directive in the login controller and it works great i have test it the success method of login request, but i want to move my logout html to the navbar which is in the index.html, so i'm not sure where to put my logic to test against the cookie ?
that's my index.html

```
    <div ng-controller="HomeController">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="/Register">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Login">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Articles">Articles</a></li>
                    <li ng-if ="isAuth" ng-click="LogOut()"><a href="/Logout">LogOut</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
</div>
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

HomeController

```
app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, Auth) {
    $scope.isAuth = Auth.IsAuth;
 });
```

Auth service

```
app.service('Auth', function ($cookieStore) {
var auth = function myfunction() {
    if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
return{
    isAuth : auth()
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If that's what you are asking, the login and logout methods should be implemented in your `Auth` service. Otherwise, try to clarify what you mean

Comment: the problem here is that Logout link in my index didn't show even if i have logged in !!

Comment: Which means that `Auth.IsAuth` is false even when you are logged in. And you should't set `isAuth` to `auth()`, but to `auth`. This way, if you call it with `Auth.IsAuth()` it will be re-evaluated